# PHP not deleting data, mySQL gives JS error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make it possible to delete data from my databas but I only get error in my PHPMyAdmin.

I have a echo which echos "This gets echoed", as you might figure, that gets echoed but the other line doesn't seem to work.

Thankful for any help!
Thanks in advance!

PHP code:

```
<a href="edit_data.php">Klicka här för att redigera data</a><br><br>
<?php
include_once"connect.php";

//Väljer data från angivna tabellen
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
echo 'This gets echoed';
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM info WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//Skriver ut data från varje rad
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo '<form action=index.php method=post>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['airport'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['code'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['land'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['conti'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['ppl'] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["lati"]. ' x ' . $row["longi"] . '<br> </td>';
    echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" /><br><br> </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</form>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM info WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};
} else {
echo "0 results"; //Skrivs ut om databasen är tom
}
?>
```

Error in PHPMyAdmin:

```
{
"pma_version": "4.4.10",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "46.0.2490.71",
"user_os": "Mac",
"server_software": "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "5.6.10",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Cannot read property '0' of null",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": 235,
            "func": "",
            "context": [
                "                lastException = null;",
                "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                "            }",
                "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                "",
                "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                "    return report;"
            ],
            "column": "",
            "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "getFieldValidators",
            "line": 302,
            "column": "40",
            "context": [
                " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                " */",
                "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                "{",
                "    // look for field bound validator",
                "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    // look for registered validators"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "validate_field",
            "line": 418,
            "column": "21",
            "context": [
                "{",
                "    var args, result;",
                "    var $field = $(field);",
                "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                "        } else {",
                "            args = [];"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
            "line": 511,
            "column": "13",
            "context": [
                "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                "        // run all field validators",
                "        var errors = {};",
                "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                "        }",
                "        // run all fieldset validators",
                "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                "        });"
            ],
            "filename": "config.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
            "line": 279,
            "column": "33",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.m.event.dispatch",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "8436",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
            "line": 374,
            "column": "19",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.r.handle",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "5139",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Object.m.event.trigger",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "7537",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "HTMLDocument.<anonymous>",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "15404",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "Function.m.extend.each",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "2973",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36",
    "incomplete": "false",
    "partial": "true",
    "uri": "sql.php?target="
},
"script_name": "sql.php",
"microhistory": {
    "current_index": "0"
}
}
```

Comment: What does PhpMyAdmin have to do with running your own PHP script?

Comment: `$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM info WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";` <-- this allows for deletion of all your data. Don't pass input direct to SQL.